# a solution for Hover and Mouse leave i jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to update the images with another image by hover in jquery 
My codes are working well, for example the first image is in blue color and when I hover it its going to update another image But the problem is when I suddenly mouse leave on first image, the first image is going to update orange image but already I leave it and its not going to blue image suddenly.

Comment: If give me reputation I can send an Image to better understanding

Comment: these are  the codes:

Comment: $("#Blue Image").hover(function () {
                $("#Orange Image").show();
               
            });

            $("#Orange Image").mouseleave(function () {
                $("#Orange Image").hide();
                
            });

Comment: Please edit your post and add your updates in the question! Also it would help if you post your related html as well.

Comment: @Caner Akdeniz check this one http://jsfiddle.net/kpo8oor5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Since `.hover()` won't be supported anymore, it is better practice to use `mouseenter()` method:

```
$("#blue").on('mouseenter',function () {
    $("#orange").show();
});
$("#orange").on('mouseleave', function () {
    $("#orange").hide();
});
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kpo8oor5/2/

Comment: you try to move your mouse suddenly and see what is happening

Comment: @kamal your question was not clear enough so i just assumed. I updated the answer for you to mark as an answer if it helped out for you.